# If Cipher fails to encode, retries will also fail

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

Lets say you have some strings that you want to encrypt with your public key and then dectrypt, which are not related with each other. But one of them doesn't accomplish the criteria (it is longer than the key bit-length can process), and you want to throw an error and continue decoding others.

Well, the thing is that if the `Data must not be longer than x bytes` exception is thrown, then **the next ones will also fail**.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent It from happening?

I made a self-explanatory code which can be used to reproduce the error:

```
Cipher encrypter;
        Cipher decrypter;

        Key pubKey;
        Key privKey;

        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

        kpg.initialize(1024);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();

        pubKey = kp.getPublic();
        privKey = kp.getPrivate();

        encrypter = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        encrypter.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

        decrypter = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        decrypter.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);

        byte[] encryptedData;
        byte[] decryptedData;


        System.out.println("Starting short test 1");
        encryptedData = encrypter.doFinal("SHORT TEST 1".getBytes());
        decryptedData = decrypter.doFinal(encryptedData);
        System.out.println(new String(decryptedData)); //SHORT TEST

        System.out.println("Starting short test 2");
        encryptedData = encrypter.doFinal("SHORT TEST 2".getBytes());
        decryptedData = decrypter.doFinal(encryptedData);
        System.out.println(new String(decryptedData)); //SHORT TEST 2

        System.out.println("Starting short test 3");
        encryptedData = encrypter.doFinal("SHORT TEST 3".getBytes());
        decryptedData = decrypter.doFinal(encryptedData);
        System.out.println(new String(decryptedData)); //SHORT TEST 3

        try {

            encryptedData = encrypter.doFinal(("LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST" +
                    " LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST" +
                    " LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST LONG TEST ").getBytes());
            decryptedData = decrypter.doFinal(encryptedData);
            System.out.println(new String(decryptedData)); // IT DOESN'T REACH HERE, WHICH IS OK

        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());  // Data must not be longer than 117 bytes (OK, fair enough, my bad)
        }

        System.out.println("Starting short test 4");
        encryptedData = encrypter.doFinal("SHORT TEST 4".getBytes());
        decryptedData = decrypter.doFinal(encryptedData);
        System.out.println(new String(decryptedData)); // THROWS THE SAME EXCEPTION THAN IN PREVIOUS TEST
```

Console print:

```
Starting short test 1
SHORT TEST 1
Starting short test 2
SHORT TEST 2
Starting short test 3
SHORT TEST 3
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 117 bytes
Starting short test 4
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 117 bytes
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:347)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:392)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2202)
    at main.main(main.java:66)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[doFinal() documentation states that](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal(byte[])):

> Note: if any exception is thrown, this cipher object may need to be
>   reset before it can be used again.

Since there's no `reset` method, I assume you have to call `init` on it again.

Answer (score 2):

[The rather direct answer of m0skit0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60123082/589259) is of course fine, but there are a few things to consider.

---

Exceptions should be avoided as much as possible (in released code). Re-encrypting the same message won't work as you would get the same exception, so for that particular message you would be out of options. If you use hybrid cryptography (next point) then you can easily avoid this issue.

---

RSA is not made to transport large amounts of data. Learn about how you can combine AES/GCM and RSA/OAEP to create a *hybrid cryptosystem* that can encrypt/decrypt any amount of data efficiently.

---

Instances of `Cipher` class are generally *lightweight*. They are relatively cheap to instantiate and initialize and don't carry much *state*. *So simply generating a new instance is much less error prone than reusing an old one.*

This means for instance that you should store **the keys** in the fields of a class, *not a `Cipher` instance itself*. As keys are immutable, that means that the state of the class remains valid, whatever happens to the `Cipher` instances.

---

### About the code / cryptography:

```
kpg.initialize(1024);
```

That's not considered a good enough key size anymore. Try 3072 or higher. Or go for Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC).

```
encrypter = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
```

never forget to specify the **full** algorithm and don't use defaults. The above uses `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` but OAEP should be preferred (but has even more overhead).

---

`String.getBytes()` and `new String(byte[])`: always specify a character set from `StandardCharsets` unless you are bound to the platform default encoding (and the subsequent decoding mistakes on another platform).

Comment: Most of that things are covered in my original code but skipped for brevity. For instance, I am using my own keys, not genering them. Anyway, I appreciate.

Comment: "Exceptions are never OK, and you should not encounter them outside of testing" Sorry but I can't agree. Exceptions do happen in perfectly fine code and do (and will) happen outside testing. It could be a hardware problem. It could be a network problem. In any case, exceptions are perfectly normal and your code should be able to gracefully recover from them if possible. Exceptions are not your enemy, they're your friend.

Comment: OK, I've rewritten it a bit, maybe that was overstated. I've now written that they should be avoided as much as possible. I don't see exceptions during runtime as my friend, to be honest. I've never thought, oh cool, there is the exception that I was expecting apart from troubleshooting. Now the exception *mechanism*... I'm a huge fan (although I'm not always happy with checked exceptions especially w.r.t Java `Cipher`). Won't even use a language that doesn't have it.

Comment: Yeah, I was referring to the mechanism of course :)